# How to change Dimple js gridlines styles

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

I want to change the style of Yaxis grid lines to dashlines. Could anyone help me on this. Thanks..

Comment: What does their documentation say?

Comment: Document doesn't not clearly specify. In their documentation they mentioned about gridline shapes. I tried, but it doesn't work. Below is the URL
https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#gridlineShapes

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but this might help someone looking to change the gridline color.
The example dimplejs website gives does not work as you pointed out.
This is because the stroke attribute will be overridden by the line STYLE.
This is from the dimplejs webpage and does change the stroke but does not display the new color.

```
myAxis.gridlineShapes.selectAll("line").attr("stroke", "#FF0000");
```

Change the **`style`** instead of the stroke attribute like this.

```
myAxis.gridlineShapes.selectAll("line").style("stroke", "#FF0000");
```